# Wireshark Dissector : IP Dissector does not recognize my protocol

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm developing a dissector/protocol as a plugin above Network layer so that  The IP dissector will dissect all the IP headers and will look at the "protocol" field to pass the payload to my protocol.
let's say the protocol number is " 254 ".

What are all the steps needed to do , so that the IP dissector will pass the payload to my protocol ?

EDIT:

my packet-temp.c file contains :

```
#include "config.h"

#include <epan/packet.h>


#define IP_PROTO_TEMP 254
static int proto_temp = -1;


static void dissect_temp(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree     *tree)
{
    col_set_str(pinfo->cinfo, COL_PROTOCOL, "TEMP");
    /* Clear out stuff in the info column */
    col_clear(pinfo->cinfo, COL_INFO);
 }

 void proto_register_temp(void)
 {
     proto_temp = proto_register_protocol (
               "TEMP Protocol", /* name       */
               "TEMP",      /* short name */
               "temp"       /* abbrev     */
               );
  }



 void proto_reg_handoff_temp(void)
{
     static dissector_handle_t temp_handle;

     temp_handle = create_dissector_handle(dissect_temp, proto_temp);
     dissector_add_uint("ip.proto", IP_PROTO_TEMP , temp_handle);
}
```

i have this file in >C:\Development\wireshark\plugins\temp   folder, since i'm writing it as a plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your dissector register itself in the `"ip.proto"` dissector table, with 254 as the key, i.e., something such as:

```
proto_my_protocol = proto_register_protocol("My Protocol", "MYP", "myp");
my_handle = new_create_dissector_handle(dissect_my_protocol, proto_my_protocol);
dissector_add_uint("ip.proto", 254, my_handle);
```

(you are probably already doing some of the above, such as the `proto_register_protocol()` call).  If your dissector isn't a "new-style" protocol, taking an extra "data" argument and returning an `int`, use `create_dissector_handle()` rather than `new_create_dissector_handle()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @GuyHarris.  I Still could not register the protocol. I saw the ipproto.c file , But i could not see my protocol number(254) there in the file. As I'm writing my dissector as a plugin , it does not affect right ?

Comment: sir I've attached the packet-temp.c file in the question. please take a look at it and suggest me where am i wrong ? thanks.

Comment: You're wrong to think that "ip.proto" is spelled "ip.port". :-)  Fix that error, i.e. use `dissector_add_uint("ip.proto", IP_PROTO_TEMP , temp_handle);` not `dissector_add_uint("ip.port", IP_PROTO_TEMP , temp_handle);`.

Comment: " I saw the ipproto.c file , But i could not see my protocol number(254) there in the file." It doesn't have to be there; Wireshark allows you to add, for example, new protocols running atop IP *without* having to modify Wireshark source itself.

Comment: sir, @GuyHarris ,  with this modification , i see that protocol number in (wireshark -> Internals ->Dissector table -> Integer tables -> ip.proto ) but it is not there in ipproto.c file. should it be not there?

Comment: It does not need to be there, as I said.  All that adding it will do is change the way the IPv4 and IPv6 dissectors display the protocol/next header field.